# syntax for updating mongo db document from command line

Tags: mongodb

I'm getting familiar with mongo db command line fiddling techniques, and have run into a snag: I can't figure out why my update attempts are failing.

I have the following documents in my 'resources'  collection:

```
db.resource.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("565e4d05bee802ae5f0c49f2"), "name" : "Spark ", "image" : [ "fake1", "fake2" ], "appName" : "zeppelin", "appVersion" : "0.6.0-snapshot-spark1.5", "appProperties" : [ { "name" : "spark.version", "value" : "1.5.1" } ], "status" : "inactive" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("565e4d17bee8cb569622d16a"), "name" : "Spark ", "image" : [ "fake1", "fake2" ], "appName" : "zeppelin", "appVersion" : "0.6.0-snapshot-spark1.5", "appProperties" : [ { "name" : "spark.version", "value" : "1.5.1" } ], "status" : "inactive" }
```

I tried to set a new name on these documents with this command:

```
db.resources.update (
  { "appName": "zeppelin"} ,
  {  $set: { "name": "zoo" }
})
```

However, I got this result (indicating that nothing was updated):

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

I'm surely doing some simple incorrect thing, and am hoping that someone who knows mongo will easily spot it and set me straight.

Thanks in advance !
 -chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collection name is wrong in the update. It is "resource" in find, where as you are using "resources" in the update.